# iOS tab bar, how to seque to a new tab bar view

Tags: objective-c, ios, storyboard, tabbar, segue

I have searched and searched but I can't find way by using segue and storyboard I can achieve having a tab-bar menu link to another page with an entirely new view with its own tab-bar and new set of menu.

Or maybe tab-bar is not even the way to go?

This is a part of schoolwork.

Answer (score 0):

Just add one more TabBarController on your storyboard and connect it with parent TabBar as another view:

[image]

Will look like this on device:

[image]

Comment: Tnx for fast response. I have tried this way, thingy is that I do not want to add an extra tab-bar but to link one of the menus in the tab-bar to a new page with its own tab-bar menu (having nothing to do with the previous views tab-bar)

Comment: or maby this goes totaly against what a tab-bar should and can do.

Comment: Toolbar is the answer!! :) i got all the control in the world from there

Comment: Goes. You want to hide tabs, than what's the point in having TabBar at all? The idea is that you have different aspects of application on tabs and you can switch between them from any point in the app. You can have 100 views in navigation stack on one of the tabs, but from any of them, you can switch to preferences (for example) on another tab with one click. Yes, you can hide tabs in some cases (Music app), but another tabbar will confuse user. And how you plan to go back to parent TabBar? You should reconsider your app architecture, there must be more user-friendly way :)

Comment: tnx for the input. I will still have homeBtn at all time, its the other btns i want to change to go to different tab-bar states. But as u mention, it kinda goes against what the tab-bar is all about.
therefor the toolbar solves the fix for me :)